# Jetty Multithreading issue

Tags: multithreading, jetty

Could you please help me on how to handle multiple threads in jetty server.
 Below is the sample code which i have written.

```java
    QueuedThreadPool threadpool = new QueuedThreadPool(100, 20);
    Server server = new Server(threadpool);

    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    handler.addServletWithMapping(TestServlet.class,
            "/JettyServer/TestServlet");
    server.setHandler(handler);
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server);
    http.setPort(9090);
    server.addConnector(http);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Problem is its not accepting multiple request.

Comment: Try adding `server.addBean(new ScheduledExecutorScheduler());`

Comment: What does `TestServlet.class` do?

Comment: It's servlet which just prints Hello Jetty!!.

Comment: Problem is not handling concurrent request. It process one thread at a time.